# Get prefix length of IPv6 from dhcpcd

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp, ipv6, dhcpcd

I use dhcpcd to acquire an IPv6 address. Is there a way to find out the prefix length of the acquired IPv6 through dhcpcd?

Added this to the dhcpcd.conf to get an IP for eth0

```
interface eth0
 ipv6rs
 ia_na 1
```

I'm getting the IPv6 details by using `dhcpcd --dumplease eth0 -6` it returns the following;

```
dhcp6_client_id='00041c24f4b34648ea8a159c1b44c'
dhcp6_ia_na1_ia_addr1='fd00::1b5'
dhcp6_ia_na1_ia_addr1_pltime='4500'
dhcp6_ia_na1_ia_addr1_vltime='7200'
dhcp6_ia_na1_iaid='00000001'
dhcp6_ia_na1_t1='0'
dhcp6_ia_na1_t2='0'
dhcp6_name_servers='fd00::1'
dhcp6_reconfigure_accept='1'
dhcp6_server_id='00010001298b05cbc25e4c55'
```

Now I'm aware I can get the prefix length from `ip address | grep fd00::1b5` command, but I'm wondering if there are other ways to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, DHCPv6 does not provide this information – you're still expected to get your local prefixes from the same ICMPv6 Router Advertisements as you do with SLAAC (indeed usually DHCPv6 is prompted by a flag in the Router Advertisement) and in most cases those are /64. Without prefix information, though, best to assume that the address is /128.

Comment: I don't have a reference to hand but I think that /64 is the minimum recommended prefix for any subnet. Actual subnets of anything other than /64 are quite rare.